# convert time before 1900 into millisecond python?

Tags: python, django

how can I convert the time before 1900 into millisecond.currently using this method:-

```
if 'dob' in json_data['data']:
                    datetimestring = str(datetime.fromtimestamp(json_data['data']['dob'] / 1000.0).strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
                else:
                    datetimestring = []
                result_data_for_editing = json_data['data']
```

and i am gettingt this error:-
`year=1084 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900`

Comment: When do you want to start counting from?

Comment: actually there is a dob feild in my database which conatin 1084 as dob and i dont know how to convert it into milliseocnds

Answer (score 2):

Just a workaround, not an actual answer!

If the year is before 1900, say 1800:
You just calculate the milliseconds from the date in the year 1900, and add milliseconds equivalent to (1900-1800=) 100 years to it.